# Redefining a theorem counter

Tags: numbering, theorems, counters

I have a document with a lot of lemmas and theorems. In the main part of the document there are sections and subsections, so I defined

```
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[subsection]
```

to number the lemmas accordingly. But in the appendices I don't have subsections, so I figured it would be better if lemmas in the appendices are not numbered with respect to subsections, but with respect to sections. Therefore, I gave the command

```
\renewcommand\thelem{\thesection.\arabic{lem}}
```

just after opening the appendices with `\appendix`. But something strange happened. In appendix A I don't have lemmas. In appendix B the first lemma is numbered B.3. Could anyone explain me this behavior and suggest a solution?

---

**Edit:** If I give the command

```
\renewcommand\thelem{\thesection.\arabic{lem}}
\setcounter{lem}{0}
```

the first lemma will be numbered B.1. But I'm still confused about why it is necessary to set the counter to 0.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your counter resets at subsections  not at sections, so

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{lem}{section}
\makeatother
```

Comment: If I do this the number of the first lemma will be B.0.1.

Comment: I meant do that at the point that you rededine the counter, not at the satrt

Comment: Ah sorry, I commented away `\renewcommand\thelem...` (which is silly, I admit). It works now, thanks!